# Excel VBA: How to create an autofilter with an exception to the filter?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am new to VBA and working on a project in which I have to filter data between two specific values (4400000000 and 5600000000). Where this gets tricky for me, is that some of the 5500000000's have letters behind them, i.e. 5500000000 CST. How can I write my code so it includes these numbers if there are letters behind them. If that is too vague, how can I write my code so it includes the CST's? Here is my code so far:

```
Sub macro5()
Worksheets("info1").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
Field:=7, _
Criteria1:=">=" & 4400000000#, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:="<5600000000, Operator:=xlFilterValues"
End Sub
```

Comment: Only the 5500000000's? Can you add a third criteria contains "5500000000"?

Comment: You may think about looping through and extracting only the numbers.  If you need to keep the letters, you can create a "helper" column that becomes the column you filter on.  You can delete the "helper" column at the end if you don't need it.

Comment: Loop through and create a dictionary of the values to filter then use the keys as criteria1 with xlfiltervalues

Comment: @Jeeped I am getting an error when trying to run your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through and create a dictionary of the values to filter then use the keys as criteria1 with xlfiltervalues.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro5()
    Dim d As Long, dict As Object
    Dim i As Double, mn As Double, mx As Double

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    mn = 4400000000#
    mx = 5600000000#

        With Worksheets("info1")
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            For d = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
                If IsNumeric(Left(.Cells(d, "G").Value2, 1)) Then
                    i = CDbl(Split(.Cells(d, "G").Value2 & Chr(32), Chr(32))(0))
                    If i >= mn And i < mx Then
                        dict.Item(CStr(.Cells(d, "G").Value2)) = .Cells(d, "G").Value2
                    End If
                End If
            Next d
            .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=dict.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: When using an array for multiple values in criteria1 with xlfiltervalues, the numbers should be text-that-looks-like-a-number for some reason.

Comment: Very clever aproach

Comment: When I ran this code I got "run time error '13': Type mismatch." When I go to debug it, it shows this line `i = CDbl(Split(.Cells(d, "G").Value2 & Chr(32), Chr(32))(0))`